# Clearing a STALL conditon in COM device with c application

Tags: c, serial-port, usb, device-management

Can I clear a STALL condition in COM device, connected by USB  using c?

The program is a application, written in C using gcc.

Now I communicating with device using function `CreateFile` for conneting and `WriteFile/ReadFile` to read, write data from windows.h.

Comment: you need to use ioctrl https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/usbioctl/

Comment: You may be able to do this by getting the source of the [devcon command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon) and porting the process equivalent to the [remove command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-remove). However, that is not always possible. Also, the devices must be `CloseHandle` before processing.

Comment: @0___________ when I using it I get invalid handle